# Set some capabilities in linux process then drop superuser privileges?

Tags: c, linux, setuid, linux-capabilities

In a C program, I have to deal with `RLIMIT_NPROC` and `RLIMIT_NOFILE` limits and additionally bind to a port less than 1024. I am thinking to run this under an unprivileged user since my program needs only two capabilities.

I saw [here](http://www.dwheeler.com/secure-programs/Secure-Programs-HOWTO/minimize-privileges.html) that I can set capabilities for the process and then drop root privileges using `setuid()`. Now, if I fork the process that will keep the set list of capabilities with it, without root privileges, then  my program will be kept running with minimal privileges.
A very rough overview of my planning:

```
int main()
{
 int nproc,nfds,port;
         /*
          *  set capabilities to the process
          *  then drop priviales
         */
   setuid(getuid()); //Drop privilages to real user id
   fork() //Now create a child apparantly which will be having parents set capabilties
   /*Now do tasks to which the whole is being played*/
   set_nproclimit(nproc);
   set_nofilelimit(nfds);
   do_bind_to_port(port);
 return 0;
}
```

Here I am lacking to use any syscall to set capabilities. Any idea of such functions will be great help.

PS: I am able to assign caps through command utility `setcap` and also using `cap_set_file()` but i want to do this in other way because I am not every time sure about path of binary.

Some helpful proc commands to check process & sub process's status `cat /proc/<PID>/task/<PID>/status`, `cat /proc/<PID>/limits`

Comment: can you be little more specific on what is it that you want, i mean i didn't understand the problem that you are facing

Comment: You need to look into [libcap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/libcap.3.html)

Comment: @dreamer Yes it sounds confusing . I Just want to assign some capability rather than running my program as root privileges.